# How to compare and count two columns and get 0 if the value not exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python, I am working on the a small analytics problem. So I compared a Dataframe with the list. So it gives value, but i need 0 which is not there in the list.

My Code :

```
    Location    Region          Category
1   Duliajan    Western Asset   PE
2   Duliajan    Western Asset   SE
3   Duliajan    Western Asset   SE
4   Duliajan    Western Asset   SE
5   HAPJAN          Central Asset   COL
6   HAPJAN          Central Asset   OTH
7   KATHAL      Central Asset   COL
8   KATHAL      Central Asset   DP-PD
9   STF         Trunk Line  PE
10  STF         Trunk Line  PE
11  STF         Trunk Line  GL
12  STF         Trunk Line  PE
13  OTHERS          Eastern Asset   OTH
14  OTHERS          Eastern Asset   OTH


a_location = ['NAGAJAN','JORAJAN','KATHAL','HEBEDA','MAKUM','BAREKURI','BAGHJAN',
        'Duliajan','LANGKASHI','HAPJAN']
category = ['DP/PD','ID','ENC','SE','COL','GL','COT','PE','FI','OTH']

df1 = df[df['Location'] .isin (a_loction)]
print(df1)

a_data = df.groupby(['Location','Category']).size().reset_index(name="count")
print(a_data)
```

My output :

```
  Unnamed: 0       Location         Region Category  
0           1  Duliajan Area  Western Asset       PE           
1           2  Duliajan Area  Western Asset       SE           
2           3  Duliajan Area  Western Asset       SE           
3           4  Duliajan Area  Western Asset       SE        
4           5         HAPJAN  Central Asset      COL           
5           6         HAPJAN  Central Asset      OTH           
6           7     KATHALGURI  Central Asset      COL           
7           8     KATHALGURI  Central Asset    DP-PD          


        Location Category  count
0  Duliajan Area       PE      1
1  Duliajan Area       SE      3
2         HAPJAN      COL      1
3         HAPJAN      OTH      1
4     KATHALGURI      COL      1
5     KATHALGURI    DP-PD      1
6         OTHERS      OTH      2
7      STF-FTNGB       GL      1
8      STF-FTNGB       PE      3
```

But I need count value 0 for which is not there in location and category list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
list_data=[
  ["Duliajan","Western Asset","PE"],
  ["Duliajan","Western Asset","SE"],
  ["Duliajan","Western Asset","SE"],
  ["Duliajan","Western Asset","SE"],
  ["HAPJAN","Central Asset", "COL"],
  ["HAPJAN","Central Asset", "OTH"],
  ["KATHAL","Central Asset", "COL"],
  ["KATHAL","Central Asset", "DP-PD"],
  ["STF","Trunk Line"  ,"PE"],
  ["STF","Trunk Line"  ,"PE"],
  ["STF","Trunk Line"  ,"GL"],
  ["STF","Trunk Line"  ,"PE"],
  ["OTHERS","Eastern Asset","OTH"],
  ["OTHERS","Eastern Asset","OTH"]
]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=list_data,columns=["Location","Region","Category"])

location =pd.DataFrame(data=['NAGAJAN','JORAJAN','KATHAL','HEBEDA','MAKUM','BAREKURI','BAGHJAN','Duliajan','LANGKASHI','HAPJAN'],columns=["Location"])


output=pd.merge(df, location, how='outer', on = 'Location')

#Your result
print(output.groupby(['Location','Category']).count())
print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
#Result with zero
print(output.groupby(['Location','Category']).count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack())
```

### Based on the comment

If you want to compare two columns then the only difference is

```
location =pd.DataFrame(data=[['NAGAJAN''DP-PD'],['JORAJAN','ID'],['KATHAL','ENC'],['HEBEDA','SE'],['MAKUM','COL'],['BAREKURI','GL'],['BAGHJAN','COT'],['Duliajan','PE'],['LANGKASHI','FI'],['HAPJAN','OTH']],columns=["Location","Category"])
 
output=pd.merge(df, location, how='outer', on = ['Location',"Category"])
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have Category list also, I want to compare that also and want 0 which is not there in the list.   category = ['DP/PD','ID','ENC','SE','COL','GL','COT','PE','FI','OTH']

Comment: @venkateswaran I answered the question based on your question please update your question to helping you with this issue.